# SharePointAuditOperation enum translation info permission

Tags: sharepoint-permissions, sdk

When calling Office365 ManagementActivity API, I get the following response:

```
{
        "CreationTime": "2020-04-15T11:21:30",
        "Id": "id",
        "Operation": "FileModified",
        "OrganizationId": "org_id",
        "RecordType": 6,
        "UserKey": "user_key",
        "UserType": 0,
        "Version": 1,
        "Workload": "SharePoint",
        "ClientIP": "ip",
        "ObjectId": "object_id",
        "UserId": "user_id",
        "CorrelationId": "correlation_id",
        "EventSource": "SharePoint",
        "ItemType": "File",
        "ListId": "list_id",
        "ListItemUniqueId": "list_item_unique_id",
        "Site": "site_id",
        "UserAgent": "MSWAC",
        "WebId": "wbe_id",
        "SourceFileExtension": "docx",
        "SiteUrl": "url",
        "SourceFileName": "Blob name",
        "SourceRelativeUrl": "reltive URL"
    }
```

This activity log is describing some action that modified the file (`"Operation": "FileModified"`) by some User.

I would like you know what User permission was used for this operation. How can I map between `SharePointAuditOperation` and the actual permission?

Answer (score 0):

The Office365 ManagementActivity API works based on the **OAuth2 access tokens**, the way other generic REST API is called from an external application to SharePoint. There it should not be direct **access to the SharePoint granular objects like a list or list item**.

It all works based on the application registration in the **Azure AD** and **the OAuth2 protocol**. The official Microsoft documentation says about this - "The API relies on Azure AD and the OAuth2 protocol for authentication and authorization. To access the API from your application, you'll need to first register it in Azure AD and configure it with appropriate permissions. This will enable your application to request the OAuth2 access tokens it needs to call the API. "

Note:

- Before you can access data through the Office 365 Management Activity
  API, you must enable unified audit logging for your Office 365
  organization. You do this by turning on the Office 365 audit log.

For details about this please refer to the below MSDN article:

[Office 365 Management Activity API reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office-365-management-api/office-365-management-activity-api-reference)

**Steps to register Application in Azure AD**

- Login to your azure portal and make sure you are in the right
  directory in which you are going to register your application.
- Click on **Azure Active Directory**.
- From left navigation panel click on **App Registration** and then New
  **Registration**
- Please enter display name in **Name** box and select any **Supported
  account types**.
- Click on **Register**.
- Once application is registered, perform following options to generate
  client secret.
- Click on Certificate and secrets.
- Then click **New client secret** and enter a certificate description
  and then click **Add**
- It displays a hashed client secret and copy it somewhere because
  later we cannot, and we need it when configuring App client call.

**How to add permission and grant tenant admin consent: -**
 - Click on **API permissions** below **Certificates and secrets** and then
   click Add a permission, this will open a new blade showing different
   API available to use.
 - Click on **Office 365 Management APIs**, it opens another popup blade
   showing the type of permissions as **Delegated** and **Application**, since
   here we are using console as sample application then we can use
   **Application** permission and same apply for background services as
   well.
 - After clicking Application permissions, it shows a list of
   permission.
 - Since we are using O365 Activity API, first we need to give
   permission related to Activity Feed and expand the same ActivityFeed
   and then select checkbox as below.
 - Then click **Add Permissions**
 - Next click on **Grant admin consent for {Tenant Name}**, it will ask
   confirmation and then click on Yes.
 - Click on the **Overview** from left navigation and copy **Application ID,
   Tenant ID** in a separate file which we need when making API call.

**How to request access tokens from Azure AD:**

Please follow below steps to set up client application with App ID, Tenant ID, Client Secrets.

- Create a sample .Net Core console application.
- Install package “Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory”,
  this is the only package we need for getting Azure AD auth tokens.
- Store client Id, tenant id and client secret in a class level
  variable as shown below.

**Make Office 365 Management Activity APIs Call Code:**

```
class Program
    {
        static string tenantId = "tenanr123";
        static string clientId = "client123";
        static string secret = "S:9Wol6h$%^$&#*dsjdnsdds-=H-PC:/rDf";
        static OAuthMessageHandler messageHandler;
        static Program()
        {
            messageHandler = new OAuthMessageHandler(tenantId, clientId, secret, new HttpClientHandler());
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StartSubscription();
            ListSubscription();
            RetrieveContent();
        }
        static void StartSubscription()
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(messageHandler))
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://manage.office.com");
                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);

                string endpoint = $"/api/v1.0/{tenantId}/activity/feed/subscriptions/start?contentType=Audit.Exchange";
                HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), endpoint);

                var resp = httpClient.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
                if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing completed");
                }
            }
        }
        static void ListSubscription()
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(messageHandler))
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://manage.office.com");
                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);

                var testResponse = httpClient.GetAsync($"https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{tenantId}/activity/feed/subscriptions/list");
                if (testResponse.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = testResponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing completed");
                }
            }
        }
        static void RetrieveContent()
        {
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(messageHandler))
            {
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://manage.office.com");
                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);

                var testResponse = httpClient.GetAsync($"https://manage.office.com/api/v1.0/{tenantId}/activity/feed/subscriptions/content?contentType=Audit.SharePoint&PublisherIdentifier={tenantId}&amp;startTime=2018-12-12&amp;endTime=2019-12-12");
                if (testResponse.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string json = testResponse.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing completed");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class OAuthMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader;
        public OAuthMessageHandler(string tenantId, string clientId, string secret, HttpMessageHandler innerHandler)
            : base(innerHandler)
        {
            var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId, false);
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientId, secret);
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
            Task runTask = Task.Run(async () => authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://manage.office.com", clientCred));
            runTask.Wait();
            string token = authenticationResult.AccessToken;

            authHeader = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                 HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Headers.Authorization = authHeader;
            return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
```

For the details explanation refer to the below article:

[How to use Office 365 Management Activity API](https://www.netwoven.com/2019/11/12/how-to-use-office-365-management-activity-api/)

Comment: How's that answer my question?

Comment: What I basically want is to map SharePointAuditOperation enum into permissions (even manually )